# How to serialize a modified object again?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I have a program that needs to repeatedly serialize the same object. However, when I serialize the object multiple times and deserialize it, the following deserializations do not show the changes made in the object.

```
public class A implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int field;

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final ObjectOutputStream writer = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("serialized_object.bin"));
        final ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("serialized_object.bin"));

        final A obj = new A();

        obj.field = 2;
        writer.writeObject(obj);

        final A deserialized1 = (A) reader.readObject();
        System.out.println("first deserialized's field: " + deserialized1.field);

        obj.field = 3;
        writer.writeObject(obj);

        final A deserialized2 = (A) reader.readObject();
        System.out.println("second deserialized's field: " + deserialized2.field);

        writer.close();
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

I want this to result:
first deserialized's field: 2
second deserialized's field: 3

Actual result:
first deserialized's field: 2
second deserialized's field: 2

Ideally, I would not have to create another instance and I would not have to output into another file either.

Comment: I tried that, but it isn't working. I think that the file isn't even reading the second serialization because the file has the original then the modified, and every time you create a new reader, you are starting from the very beginning of the file. And, I don't want to start the writer again because I want both versions to be in one file at the end and starting the writer again would reset the file so that only the modified version is stored.

Comment: You are assuming that you can have a reader and a writer both open on the same file, and that the reader will see the data written by the writer cleanly. Given that there may be buffering involved I think this is a dubious assumption.

Comment: But your real problem is that the same object will only be written once: "Multiple references to a single object are encoded using a reference sharing mechanism so that graphs of objects can be restored to the same shape as when the original was written."

Comment: One solution is to call `reset()` before writing each object. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#reset() But note that affects all objects.

Comment: But do you want the whole history in the file? Why not just close the files after reading/writing each object -- it isn't expensive.

Comment: @tgdavies I was working on a multiplayer game and I wanted to send packets based on the same objects multiple times. In my project, I am not actually writing to a file but the problem still persisted because I am using the same socket and object output stream multiple times. But now, it works because of the reset().